# How do I configure a UITableViewCell to hide it's control and display a chevron?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview, uinavigationbar

A good example of the behavior I'm trying to illustrate is when you click on the "Edit" button in the iOS Clock app, the on/off switch transforms into a chevron.

I have a `UITableView` that contains a cell with a switch control on it.  When the user click the "Edit" button in the `UINavigationBar`, I'd like the switch to go away and get replaced with a chevron.  I'm new to iOS development, so up to this point I really only understand how to change the editing mode of the `UITableView` and delete cells.

How do I configure a `UITableViewCell` to hide it's switch control and display the chevron when the user clicks the "Edit" button in the `UINavigationBar`?

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be better to actually set your `cell.editingAccessoryView` to your UISwitch object, and just have the `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;`.  That way, when the user hits the Edit button, your chevron will slide out and your UISwitch will slide in without any additional work on your part.

Comment: You're welcome!  I just did something very similar, so it was fresh in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you check if the tableView is in edit mode. If it is in regular mode you set the accessoryView to the switch object. If it's in edit mode you set the accessoryView to nil and the accessoryType to UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator (the "chevron").

Answer (score 0):

You want `cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;`
and `cell.accessoryView = cellSwitch;` to achieve this.